# Web mapping within ASP MVC 3 framework

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, enterprise-geodatabase, asp.net

Just curious if anyone has used the ASP MVC 3 framework for creating web mapping applications.  I have one coming up and am planning on using the ArcGIS javascript API.  Would be interested in hearing if anyone has had success or their pitfalls using this framework.  Anyone try connecting to SDE with MVC3?

Answer (score 5):

As good as ArcGIS is, you don't need to use it.  A lot of the MVC3 crowd (Myself included) are using the following 3 Open source projects off Codeplex these days:

Dot Spatial : http://dotspatial.codeplex.com/

Sharp Map : http://sharpmap.codeplex.com/

and

Bru Tile : http://brutile.codeplex.com/

all three of them are capable of interfacing to everything from humble shape files right through to massive PostGIS databases as well as all the latest MS-SQL 2008 versions with spatial support.

The code behind most of these projects is our good old friends Gdal, Proj4 and the many other things that sit behind 90% of the GIS software on the planet.

Add to that the likes of Quantum GIS ( My Desktop GIS of choice) : http://www.qgis.org/

and you also have a fantastic tool to preview and manipulate your data.

Getting the data in/out of your projects database and performing general ETL and transforming queries on it ready for your projects to use is where the final bit of the puzzle comes in - Geo Kettle : http://www.spatialytics.org/projects/geokettle/

and you have a full suite for any GIS developer on the .NET platform...

Comment: Thanks for the info and links.  Like it or not, the shop I work in is pretty tightly tied to ESRI.  It's what the other developers and DB folks know. There's no way I am going to get approval to use overhead to train the whole team on a new set of open source technologies.  Maybe in my non-existent down time though...

Comment: I feel your pain, I've worked in places like that before where no alternatives are ever considered, oh and the non-existent downtime... yea I know that too... that's why I went back to contracting.  If you get chance though, you should take a look it's good stuff, can't help with ESRI though sorry, it's been a long time since I used that, I do believe they have an SDK download available on their developer site.